# How to check on a HTTP response while continuing to post data with HttpWebRequest

Tags: post, stream, httpwebrequest

I need to post data to a REST server. This data is dynamic and so I don't know how large it will be while I am sending the post as I am getting it in real time from another location. However, the server replies when enough data has been received.

I tried using HttpWebRequest to do this. However, if I call BeginGetResponse before writing to the request stream, then writing to the request stream causes an exception. Apparently, getting the response prevents me from sending additional info. How can I tell whether the server sent a response without getting the actual response?

Here is the code.

```
async private Task SendDataFile(ChannelParameters cp)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://" + Properties.Settings.Default.dnn_servers[0] + ":" + Properties.Settings.Default.dnn_ports[0]);
        string request_uri = "http://" + Properties.Settings.Default.dnn_servers[0] + ":" + Properties.Settings.Default.dnn_ports[0] + String.Format("/v1/speech:recognize/{0}?key={1}&confidence-threshold={2}&do-endpointing={3}",
          cp.current_name, rest_app_key, Properties.Settings.Default.usConfidenceThreshold, Properties.Settings.Default.endpointing);


        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(request_uri);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = false;
        httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        httpWebRequest.SendChunked = true;
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = Properties.Settings.Default.Resource.ToString();
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        //st.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        //st.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        //...
        switch (main_window.parameters.stream_format)
        {
            case 0:
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "audio/L16; rate=8000";
                break;
            case 1:
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "audio/PCMU; rate=8000";
                break;
            case 2:
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "audio/PCMA; rate=8000";
                break;

        }
        httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), httpWebRequest);

        //httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), httpWebRequest); can't remove the comment on this line.
        allDone.WaitOne();

    }

    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

        done_stream = false;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the operation
        Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        while (stream_data_event.WaitOne() && !done_stream)
        {
            stream_data_event.Reset();
            long write_position = main_window.stream_memory.Position;
            main_window.stream_memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            try
            {
                postStream.Write(main_window.stream_memory.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)write_position);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                main_window.AddToLog(e.ToString());
            }
            main_window.stream_memory.Position = 0;

        }
        postStream.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        ////done_stream = true;
        main_window.StopRecord();
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();
        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
        allDone.Set();
    }
```

Anyone ever try something like this?

Comment: Continuing my testing, I switched from HttpWebRequest to HttpClient. This didn't help much. HttpClient exhibits the same behavior exactly. I need a way to peak into the result stream without actually taking it.